# How to determine a tar archive's format

Tags: linux, posix, command-line-interface, gnu, tar

In Linux, how can I determine the format which was used to create a given tarball?

I'd like to detect whether a given archive was created using *posix* or *gnu* format.

I've already read the [man page for GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC134), which explains how to control the format during creation. However, I don't see anything about how to view the format of an existing file.

Comment: Also asked here:  http://superuser.com/questions/759006/how-to-find-tar-format-of-archive , which suggests 7zip on Windows for inspection.

Comment: Just a small [X-Y](http://xyproblem.info/) solution - if you come here looking for an answer as to why your generated tar.gz is being rejected/reported as invalid by some other system (regardless of what scheme/mode you use), try analyzing its structure. I was struggling with GNU/POSIX modes with no luck, until I checked and realized my generated tar.gz didn't contain folder entries (only files) which was actual cause for it being rejected by a remote system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `file` under Linux to look at the fingerprint of the uncompressed archive:

```
$ touch foo                                 # create test file
$ tar --format=posix -cf posix.tar foo      # create test posix archive
$ tar --format=gnu   -cf gnu.tar   foo      # create test gnu archive
$ file posix.tar gnu.tar
posix.tar: POSIX tar archive
gnu.tar:   POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

If the archive is compressed, decompress it first, because `file` won't peer beyond the compression layer:

```
$ touch foo                                 # create test file
$ tar --format=posix -czf posix.tar.gz foo  # create test gzip posix archive
$ tar --format=gnu   -czf gnu.tar.gz   foo  # create test gzip gnu archive
$ file posix.tar.gz gnu.tar.gz              # show output when compressed
posix.tar.gz: gzip compressed data
gnu.tar.gz:   gzip compressed data
$ gunzip posix.tar.gz                       # decompress to posix.tar
$ gunzip gnu.tar.gz                         # decompress to gnu.tar
$ file posix.tar gnu.tar                    # show output after decompression
posix.tar: POSIX tar archive
gnu.tar:   POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Or, check the compressed archives without saving the decompressed file by piping the output directly to `file`'s standard input:

```
$ gunzip --stdout posix.tar.gz | file -
/dev/stdin: POSIX tar archive
$ gunzip --stdout gnu.tar.gz | file -
/dev/stdin: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

GNU is based on an older POSIX format, so that is why it says it is both.

For the nitty gritty details, the format is described in the GNU tar manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_68.html) and more details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html).

Comment: Yes, I was just about to answer my own question with this. The problem I had is that `file` was useless if the archive was compressed. So, I had to decompress it first. Thanks for the (quick) answer! If you update the response to note that the archive must be decompressed first, I'll accept this as the solution.

Comment: I made an edit to expand a bit more. Thank you for the helpful answer.

Comment: @christopher I also just tried `tarfile` under Python 2 and 3, and `tar = tarfile.open("posix.tar")` and `tar = tarfile.open("gnu.tar")` both end up with a  `tar.format` equal to 1, which is `tarfile.GNU_FORMAT`.

Comment: You can also do `cat foo.tar.gz | gunzip | file -` to identify data from standard input. Then `foo.tar.gz` is not decompressed in the file system into `foo.tar`, but stays intact.

Comment: @Lassi Thanks. I updated the post to show that as an option, but without cat and using only one pipe.